# Adding C++ include/lib folders in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, react-native

I have include directories and static libs **outside** of my Android Studio project that I want to reference. Have looked at the docs but no dice. (The closest thing seems to be reference to "Link C++ Project with Gradle" which simply does not exist as an option inside the editor)

Android studio v2.2.0, Gradle 2.14.x

How do I do that?